# Pymongo find() with "$toString" projection operator

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I want to query a mongo object getting the `_id` as a string instead of an ObjectId.

```py
def get_obj():
    query = {} 
    contents = {
        'UniqueId' : True,
        'Name' : True,
        'Address1' : True,
        'id' : {
            "$toString": "$_id"
        }
    }
    return db.get_db().collection.find(query,contents)
```

When I run it this way I get this output:

```
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: Unsupported projection option: id: { $toString: "$_id" }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that your issue is that your are using an `aggregate` function (`$toString`) without doing an aggregation.

There are at least 2 options:

1. Just use the python `str()` method.

```py
cursor = list(get_obj())
print([str(doc['_id']) for doc in cursor])
```

2. Use aggregation

```py
def get_obj():
    contents = [
        {'$project': {
            '_id': {'$toString': '$_id'},
            # other desired fields
        }}
    ]
    return db.get_db().collection.aggregate(contents)


result = list(get_obj())

print([doc for doc in result])
```